# Price inclusive and exclusive of tax are the same in catalogue and shouldn't be

Tags: magento-1.9, price, tax

I have a part with a 20c price. This price is exclusive of GST/Tax.

When I checkout, the basket has the product displaying  as 22c which is great.
The checkout totals and sub totals are all handling the GST/Tax correctly, but the product in the catalogue is showing as 20c.

I've set it up for display purposes to show both the ext and incl values, and they are both 20c.

Any thoughts on getting the actual Incl Tax to display in the catalogue would be appreciated.

### Configuration Tax Settings:

> Tax Calculation Method based on: Row Total Tax Calculation Based On:
> Billing address Catalog Prices: Excluding Tax
>
> Enable Corss Border Trade: No
>
> Default Country: Australia Default State: * Default Post Code: 2280
>
> Display Product Prices in Catelog: Including and Excluding Tax

If I've missed relevant settings please comment and I'll add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was helpful in pointing me to the right answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9839749/692328

My **Not Logged In** Customer Group was allocated to a different tax class. I updated that and everything ticked through as expected.